# Camera compatibility

Tags: webcam, directshow, device-driver

I have an usb-camera with its drivers and dll with some functions to use this camera in my solutions. I want to use it in any wide-spread applications, to be able just to choose and use it in Skype, for instance. So. I want to develop something that will allow me to use this device as usual web-camera.
I've heard something about such technologies as "Upper-Level Filter Drivers" and "user-mode DirectShow source filter". Looks like it something that can help.

So the question is: what technologies exist for such tasks? What technology should I choose to solve my problem if I have no skills of driver development?

Comment: Skype says: "no directShow Filters anymore" [link](http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Desktop-API/directshow-devices-no-longer-available-in-skype/td-p/15148) :`(

Answer (score 0):

Skype still uses DirectShow for video capture and user mode filter will do the job. Still Skype makes certain unreasonable assumptions that limit compatible source filters, such as if the developers stopped development/testing as soon as they had their favorite USB cam working and ignoring all other devices users might possibly want to attach.

One of the options you were suggested (in Russian - [1](http://forum.wonderu.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1410), [2](http://forum.wonderu.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1413)) was to develop a kernel mode driver so that your device is visible to apps through standard [`WDM Video Capture Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is possible and would work, though in my opinion it is a huge overkill.

Fitting custom source filter is not easy because Skype does not like a debugger attached, however driver development is really a completely different story.

The Skype Forum link you refer to is clearly misleading. The poster complains that Skype update broke compatibility with video sources. And response from admin is about audio devices, and is irrelevant.